# Trying to secure a code

Tags: assembly, tampering

I am trying to make hard to a code to be modified. Security is my concern.

Ok, I know what you guys will say about piracy, bla bla bla. Lets refrain from that discussion.

I am trying to collect ideas to do things differently in code.

Things like this for example:

```
int delta = value1 - value2;

if (delta > 0) {
   // code is fine
} else {
   // code is tampered
}
```

can be easily patched in binary by simply replacing the binary equivalent to the ">" that would be the instruction `JG` (jump if greater) with `JLE` (jump if less or equal) or even by replacing the subtraction with addition.

In this case specifically what techniques I can use instead?

What tricks do you guys know to make simple things hard for crackers?

Answer (score 5):

Ultimately, any code will be reduced to machine code / opcodes. The result is the same, but lets discuss both distributing source code and compiled/machine code:

If you are using something like PHP where you have the sourcecode, you could add more loops and constructs, but someone can just load a debugger and trace through your code anyway to strip away the access. If you have a contractual obligation or license obligation to provide sourcecode this is not going to make happy customers. If you want to add obfuscations at the higher level language level, this will make the code difficult to manage. Adding in obfuscations using a script afterwards, again you can just strip it out. When JavaScript and CSS are minified, it is annoying to trace through but not impossible. For PHP and similar, you can compile to opcodes (e.g., [ioncube](http://www.ioncube.com/)) and add obfuscation, but it doesn't stop someone from tracing though.

For compiled code: Higher level language constructs will be reduced to more simple instructions. Your compiler does a whole lot of things under the hood that may reduce all this effort you are doing at the higher level. Again, they can always step through your code with a debugger. Obfuscation is adding complexity and confusion, but there still needs to be an execution path for the correct instructions. You would be better off performing the obfuscation at compile time or performing the obfuscation on the compiled code then trying to complicate your source code. See these SO overflow questions:

- [C/C++ compiler generating obfuscated code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111808/c-c-compiler-generating-obfuscated-code)
- [How Effective is Obfuscation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551892/how-effective-is-obfuscation)

---

If you are not using a special algorithm, if people can observe the flow, they will just duplicate it *by sight and function* rather than wasting time to get the source. In the end, they can still copy your **functionality** regardless of your obfuscation.

---

The other question you may be asking is detecting if your source file was modified before/while being run. E.g., this is no longer my legitimate code so I will not run? You can do this at the file system level using [file integrity monitoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_integrity_monitoring), like [TripWire](http://www.tripwire.com/it-security-software/scm/file-integrity-monitoring/). You could also utilize [DRM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management#Software_tampering). Things like [DEP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Execution_Prevention) also help prevent this.
 If someone has a patch or hack against your code, they would likely be able to circumvent any in app protections when putting in their malicious code as well.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is obfuscation. And for your specific example control flow obfuscation.

For example, you could add needless ifs and goto statements:

```
if (!this_is_always_true_and_defined_somewhere_else) {
    goto some_label;
} else {
    if (delta > 0) {
       // code is fine
    } else {
       // code is tampered
    }
}
```

You can also make the if query more complicated:

```
if (!this_is_always_true_and_defined_somewhere_else) {
    goto some_label;
} else {
    if (delta > 0 && complicated_expression_that_is_always_true) {
       // code is fine
    } else {
       // code is tampered
    }
}
```

And of course you can do the same for the subtraction:

```
int delta = (value1 - value2) + (value3 - 4 * value4);
```

where value3 and value4 are defined elsewhere and value3 = 4 * value4

For more resources about obfuscation see [here](http://palizine.plynt.com/issues/2005Oct/hiding-control-flows/), [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/three-control-flow-obfuscation) and [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.39.5745)

There are a lot of obfuscators out there, and I would use one of them instead of making your code harder to read. But in general, I think that obfuscation doesn't really solve anything. That's why DRM still exists :)

**Edit from @TeunVink's comment** - If you use a compiler to generate a binary version of your program, make sure you know how it works. A lot of compilers do dead code analysis, which removes any unreachable parts of the code. This defeats a lot of these examples since the (pre)compiler will just replace or remove the added complexity.

Comment: @tim "That's why DRM still exists" - and also why DRM systems would routinely get bypassed by the likes of DJD Jon http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jon_Lech_Johansen :) As we know. no code can ever be 100% protected, only made as difficult as possible to reverse.

Answer (score 0):

The links posted by others here on obfuscation are worth a read. As you note yourself, a single point of testing can be easily patched to knock out tests. There may be mileage in utilising side effects that cause unrelated code breaking further on unless important code has run and left particular values lying around, and also for code to break if such values indicate that an important test such as a license check has failed. The aim would be to require a reverse engineer to gain a deeper understanding of the code than simply identifying an "if (license_check_valid)" codepoint, and for them to determine what state they would need to fake via patching to enable code to be bypassed or not run as intended and yet still leave the program operational.

Optimisers are likely to undo simple control flow obfuscations. In languages such as C/C++, techniques such as using function pointers for calls and exploding these into their constituent bytes at discrete locations so that they are never stored together and only reassembled in order to make a call may complicate analysis.

Comment: Also of note is the ability to redirect pointers to take control of a system and/or execute arbitrary and malicious code.  By exploding them and not storing them together it acts as a mitigation to this form of compromise.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the language and environment , I have had success with encrypting executable code and decrypting it on the fly. Changing the key between minor versions slows down cracks significantly, 
As does comparison of code in ram vs encrypted code checks at runtime.

Grabbing the pointer to an auth function, calculating it's checksum and comparing it against something that is known at some unrelated place in the code and then causing "minor faults" in the software ( eg for a game dropping the frame rate or introducing glitches for a scientific application throwing stats slightly off to the point where a cracker may not notice but a user would be very very aware )

Timers are also great, you can innocently look like you have some leftover debug/ profiling code when really you are watching for an application which is being debugged . Same goes for watching to see if interrupt tables are being messed with or nmi's are being thrown.

Another personal trick I like to use is taking parts of the registration key and using them as constants elsewhere in the code in unrelated places , again the key is not making the initial crack to get the software to run easy but moreso making the software behave incorrectly in subtle ways when cracked.